# Why is my body text overlapping with my image when I change the window size?

Tags: html, css

When my window is full, the text and image are in the right place, but whenever I change the size of my window, the image and the text overlap.

Here is an example of what it looks like:

What it looks like full-screened (what I want)
[image: What it looks like full-screened (what I want)]

What it looks like minimized (what I don't want)
[image: What it looks like minimized (what I don't want)]

Here is what my code is for this:

```css
.about-me {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E9E5F5;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}

.abtme {
  padding-top: -10px;
}

#abtme-par {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 830px;
  padding-top: -100px;
  text-align: left;
}

#aboutme-title {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #F0B4FF;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
}

#abbypic {
  width: 440px;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-me">
  <div class="abtme">
    <span class="abtme-pic">
      <h2 id="aboutme-title">About Me</h2>
      <img id ="abbypic" src="media/rainbowpic.jpg">
    </span>
    <p id="abtme-par">HEYYYYYYYYY mueghurhogeji rhurehugjguarejuaguhurhgirgjsugjruigj irgjuerhurHGIRUHGUIRGHUIREHGIRJGORJHIORRE HGUgrurhgiuREJGIJrehrijgREIGUEWHGIUHGIuhguirghiURHGIRwhgiruhguoewphgoHGOPURHGURHGPOWG IHGurhgireuhguiRHGIUrhguhrguhruhwgrihguhiuerhrauhgiotjhioj
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the text on the right and the image on the left when resizing. Try to add `position: absolute` to the `abtme-pic` and `abtme`, then set their widths to `50%` and height to `100%`. And add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to the `abtme` div